# Slow Update with Firebase in Android Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, navigation-drawer

I've just started with Firebase and I am not entirely sure, that my approach is the right one, so maybe someone could help me out there.

```
public class CharakterFragment extends Fragment {

String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference testRef = database.getReference("charakter/1/Name");

String wert;

public CharakterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    testRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            wert = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + wert);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_charakter, container, false);

    Log.d(TAG, "Value in view: " + wert);

    TextView textNameValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNameValue);
    textNameValue.setText(wert);

    return view;
}

}
```

The problem here is, that as soon as I load the Fragment ( I am using a Navigation Drawer Activity ), it takes about a second until the textView gets its update and until then it shows the predefined value.

Is there anything I could do to preload it or speed the process up? Also, is this the right approach to handle retrieving the data?

Edited the code according to the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the firebase addValuEventListener() method from onCreate(), so you'll get all the data from panel before showing th view. Then just set the data in onCreateView()

Comment: I've updated the code in the topic, doesn't matter how I try, it just doesn't work. Log says "Value in view: null" BEFORE "Value is: Simon"

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this app? By that I mean, is it just an application with users and profiles, like social media or is it a game (It might be relevant to your question)

Usually, with apps that gather data from an online API like firebase, latest data is cached to the device using whatever file format you choose. ([THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) might help you decide). Once that data is saved, you load it into your layout's views when the app loads, at the same time calling your API from firebase. This way your layout won't have their predefined values showing while the fetched results are loading.

Think of an app like Facebook or Twitter. Your news feed has the last few status updates you saw when you last exited the app, and after a few seconds, the newly fetched newsfeed automatically refreshes, without you having to pull to refresh.

Comment: As funny as it may sound, it's something in between. The goal is an app to manage a Pen & Paper roleplaying game. For once, Charakter Values might not change at all for an entire evening, or maybe once a day, but on the other side the app might also handle a fight. The dice rolling is still all done manually without the app, just the values change, like hitpoints etc.